Azure Data Factory (ADF) validate data types from incoming csv
My use case is to pick a .csv file which comes from a datalake container, validate the datatypes of the data included in the .csv (if data types are not valid fail the pipeline) and finally load the data into a DB table.
Within a dataflow, in a datasource transformation, in the projection tab, I did a detect data type and it accurately it discovers the data type of some fields.


I also picked this option of validate schema which is supposed if the data type of data does not match the projection.


To artificially test it, I uploaded a .csv with str type where an int should be expected.
The dataflow did NOT fail though.
Any ideas on how to meet the above-mentioned requirement?

Can you add vakues which you tried

Validate Schema option checks the structure of source data and sink data if its mismatch it will throw an error.

Any ideas on how to meet the above-mentioned requirement?

To detect if column mismatched is you can use the assert transformation and Fil the data flow if datatype mismatched.

Take assert transformation and check the Fail data flow option and set the assert transformation as below for string and integers.

For String  expression: iif(isInteger(Colname),false(),true())
For Integer  expression: iif(isInteger(colname),true(),false())



think of having more than 150 columns and this changes quite often. Nevertheless, it's a valid solution that I also figured out
